# Should $S^{-1}=\Lambda^{-1} S^{-1}A$ or $S^{-1}=\Lambda S^{-1}A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, and that $AS=S\Lambda$.
$$
\begin{align*}
AS=S\Lambda\\
A^{-1}AS=A^{-1}S\Lambda\\
S=A^{-1}S\Lambda\\
S^{-1}=(A^{-1}S\Lambda)^{-1}\\
S^{-1}=\Lambda^{-1}S^{-1}(A^{-1})^{-1}\\
S^{-1}=\Lambda^{-1} S^{-1}A\\
\end{align*}
$$

So I got $S^{-1}=\Lambda^{-1} S^{-1}A$.

But if I do it the other way round,
$$
\begin{align*}
AS=S\Lambda\\
ASS^{-1}=S\Lambda S^{-1}\\
A=S\Lambda S^{-1}\\
S^{-1}A=S^{-1}S\Lambda S^{-1}\\
S^{-1}AA^{-1}=\Lambda S^{-1}A^{-1}\\
S^{-1}=\Lambda S^{-1}A^{-1}\\
\end{align*}
$$
To my surprise, I got $S^{-1}=\Lambda S^{-1}A^{-1}$ ! The $A$ in this is an inverse, which didn't happen in the one above. Weird.

Should $S^{-1}=\Lambda^{-1} S^{-1}A$ or $S^{-1}=\Lambda S^{-1}A^{-1}$ be the correct equation? Why is this like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are. To see this, note that $AS=S\Lambda$ **AND** that $\tilde AS=S\tilde \Lambda$ for other matrices $\tilde A$ and $\tilde \Lambda$, namely $\tilde A=A^{-1}$ and $\tilde \Lambda=\Lambda^{-1}$. Hence every relation involving $(A,\Lambda)$ holds with $(\tilde A,\tilde\Lambda)$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the first derivation you got $\Lambda^{-1}$ into the mix (note the last line), not $\Lambda^1$ like in the second one.

Comment: Thanks! Corrected the typo. So now it is: Should $S^{-1}=\Lambda^{-1} S^{-1}A$ or $S^{-1}=\Lambda S^{-1}A^{-1}$ be correct.

Comment: Yes. The equivalence of the two expressions can be derived from $A^2=S\Lambda^2 S^{-1}$ via left multiplication by $\Lambda^{-1}S^{-1}$ and right multiplication by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: So I could simply say $S^{-1}=\Lambda^{-1} S^{-1}A=\Lambda S^{-1}A^{-1}$ that they are all the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same.